# Ecto Join based on custom key field name

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to get `join` to work using Ecto. Ecto seems to default to 'id' as the key field for join condition. Tried to change it to list_id and user_id using the foreign key settings in the schema, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

```
query =
          from(i in SgListItems,
            join: l in assoc(i, :sg_lists),
            join: u in assoc(i, :sg_users),
           select: [l.list_id, i.item_id]
          )
```

is translated into

```
SELECT s1."list_id", s0."item_id" FROM "sg_list_items" AS s0 INNER JOIN "sg_lists" AS s1 ON **s1."id"** = s0."list_id" INNER JOIN "sg_users" AS s2 ON **s2."id"** = s0."author_id" ) []
```

The schema for sg_lists for instance is as follows:

```
 @primary_key {:list_id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "sg_lists" do
    field(:list_title, :string, null: false)
    field(:list_description, :map, null: false)

    has_many(:sg_list_items, MyApp.SgListItems, foreign_key: :list_id)
    timestamps()
  end
```

Schema for sg_list_items below.

```
 @primary_key {:item_id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "sg_list_items" do
    belongs_to(:sg_lists, MyApp.SgLists, foreign_key: :list_id, type: :binary_id)
    field(:item_hierarchy, :map, null: false)
    field(:item_title, :string, null: false)
    field(:item_description, :map, null: false)
    belongs_to(:sg_users, MyApp.SgUsers, foreign_key: :author_id, type: :binary_id)
    timestamps()
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the field to join on, by using the `:on` option of `join`.

Try something like:

```
query =
  from(i in SgListItems,
    join: l in assoc(i, :sg_lists), on: [id: i.list_id],
    join: u in assoc(i, :sg_users), on: [id: i.user_id],
    select: [l.list_id, i.item_id]
  )
```

On this line: `[id: i.list_id]`, `id` refers to `:sg_lists`'s `id`, and on the next line, it refers to `:sg_users`'s one.

If you want to use different fields from `:sg_list` or `:sg_users`, you should put those instead of `:id`, and replace `i.list_id` for the correct field from `SgListItems`

This should work.

You can even add multiple conditions to the `:on` option, something like:

`on: [id: i.user_id, other_field: i.other_field]` would work as well. But I think what you need is just like in the snippet above.